# Strdup() not working

Tags: c, string, strdup

Probably it is very basic and everyone will shout at me, but I've been trying to fix that for hours and can't take it anymore.
I have this structure

```
struct node
{
Key_Type element;
tree_ptr left, right;
};
```

And I am trying to put a word into element using strdup like that:

```
newNode->element = strdup(word);
```

I understand that it's probably not working because I am trying to allocate a pointer to a normal variable, but I don't know how to fix that.

```
Table insert(Key_Type word,Table root)
{ 
struct node *newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
struct node *left = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
struct node *right = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
newNode = root->head;
//fprintf (stderr, "Hi\n");
while(newNode->element != NULL)
{
    //printf("%s",word);
    if(strcmp(word,newNode->element) == 0)
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "Hi\n");
        return root;
    }
    while(strcmp(word,newNode->element) == -1)
    {
        //fprintf (stderr, "Hi\n");
        newNode = newNode->left;
        //fprintf (stderr, "Hi\n");
    }//if
    //fprintf (stderr, "Hi\n");
    while(strcmp(word,newNode->element) == 1)
    {
            //fprintf (stderr, "Hi\n");
            newNode = newNode->right;
            //fprintf (stderr, "Hi\n");
    }//else if
}
//createNode(word);
newNode->element = strdup(word);
newNode->left = left;
newNode->right = right;
//fprintf (stderr, "Hi\n");
//printf("%s",root->head->element);
   return root;
}
```

Comment: how does it "not work" ? and can you show how `word` was declared, and how its current value was assigned ?

Comment: what is word and what is Key_type?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Not compiling? Crashing? Be precise.

Comment: ans also how is `Key_Type` defined?

Comment: I get segmentation error. Key_Type is indeed a char pointer

Comment: Where do you get the segmentation error? Have you tried a debugger?

Comment: is `Key_Type` a `char*`? if not, then make node.element as `char*`. `strdup` takes a `char*` & returns a `char*`.

Comment: also, Change `fprintf (stderr, "Hi\n");` to `fprintf (stderr, "Hi%d\n",__LINE__);`... it will help you more :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extending upon @unwind's answer, `strdup()` is not a standard C function, and is available on POSIX complaint systems only. Chances are you do not have an `strdup` implemented in your system.

Here is a possible implementation of `strdup()`

```
char *strdup(const char *c)
{
    char *dup = malloc(strlen(c) + 1);

    if (dup != NULL)
       strcpy(dup, c);

    return dup;
}
```

Comment: @Aniket Note though, that user code is not allowed to define functions whose names start with `str` followed by a lower-case letter. [That space is reserved](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Reserved-Names.html). Also, if you want to be efficient, it's better to use `memcpy()` on strings when the length is known.

Comment: @unwind you are free to edit the answer as required. I place my answers to the community and don't own any copyright